# COUNT in COUNT OVER PARTITION SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT MobilePhone, COUNT(MobilePhone) OVER(PARTITION BY MobilePhone) AS CountMobilePhone
FROM ES_TABLE 
WHERE applic IN ( SELECT appl 
                FROM Campaign JOIN Client ON Campaign.ClientID = Client.ClientID 
                WHERE Client.ClientCode = 'OPIS')
```

thats my query

the output is

```
MobilePhone  | CountMobilePhone
121928       |    1
912819       |    1
129819       |    3
198219       |    5
918298       |    5
```

I want to group by CountMobilePhone for counting. to be like this

```
Count   | CountMobilePhone
2       |    1
1       |    3
2       |    5
```

is that possible? I've tried several times but getting error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do another aggregation on the counts themselves:

```
SELECT CountMobilePhone, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(MobilePhone) OVER(PARTITION BY MobilePhone) AS CountMobilePhone
    FROM ES_TABLE 
    WHERE applic IN (SELECT appl FROM Campaign INNER JOIN Client
                         ON Campaign.ClientID = Client.ClientID 
                     WHERE Client.ClientCode = 'OPIS')
) t
GROUP BY CountMobilePhone
ORDER BY CountMobilePhone;
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(

SELECT 
    MobilePhone, 
    COUNT(MobilePhone) OVER(PARTITION BY MobilePhone) AS CountMobilePhone
    FROM ES_TABLE 
    WHERE EXISTS  ( SELECT  1
                    FROM Campaign JOIN Client ON Campaign.ClientID = Client.ClientID 
                    WHERE Client.ClientCode = 'OPIS' AND appl = ES_TABLE.applic)

)
SELECT
    [Count] = COUNT(1),
    CountMobilePhone
    FROM CTE
        GROUP BY CountMobilePhone
```

I've also replaced the IN with exists for better performance

Comment: thanks it works . but i see answer from tie biegelsien first . but i vote for you

Comment: One other improvement you could make would be to not select `MobilePhone` in the CTE, since it isn't really needed to tally the counts.

Comment: it's fine. we need the issue resolved with the best way that's all